# "git config --list" shows duplicate names

Tags: git

`git config --list` shows two values for `user.name`, one global, one local:

```
user.name=My Name
...
user.name=My Other Name
...
```

My understanding is that local values override global ones.  How can I get `git config` to only show the values that are actually in effect?  I only want to see one value of user.name -- the one that will be used if I commit in the current context.

If my question is based on a misunderstanding, or if this is caused by something wrong with my git install, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: When `git config --list` iterates through configuration entries, it does them in the same order that other Git commands see them.  For settings like `user.name` and `user.email`, the *last setting* is the one that is used.  (A few items, such as `remote.origin.fetch`, use *all* the settings.)  To see the value that would be used for any particular item, you can run `git config --get <item>`.  See Abhay Saraf's answer as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to get the actual value used for a variable, then `git config --list` is not the right tool. `--get` will just work.

Answer (score 38):

On Git version 2.8.0 and above, you can type

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

to show the origin of the individual configuration entry.

Order of preference is `local` > `global` > `system`. So local configuration will be preferred over global if present.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Git, so maybe experienced users don't have trouble with this. But to me it is an odd design decision that `git config --list` and `git config --list --show-origin` show values which may actually be invalid, but I can only be sure by looking through the whole list to see if the same name occurs again further down.

Comment: None of the values are "invalid", the multi-level configuration allows customization depending on scenarios. Typically for `user.name` and `user.email`, a developer should be using `global` setting only. Those values shouldn't be present in `local` (shared by multiple collaborators on that repo) or `system` (shared by multiple users on that OS) config files.

Comment: As of git version 2.7.4: `error: unknown option 'show-origin'`.

Comment: @devius I am not seeing that on git version 2.18.0, please see if you can upgrade. It might have been a bad build.

Comment: @AbhaySaraf That feature was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70bd879ab66aeee809306908e3551d50cdf06802) and published with git version 2.8.0.

Comment: In my case if have three file paths `file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"` and        
`file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig` and 
`file:C:/Users/<my-user>/.gitconfig`.  Which one is system and which is global? Could it be that the cause of having 3 paths is that two different git-clients are installed?

Comment: @surfmuggle when you type the command `git config --list --show-origin`, the settings are shown in hierarchy. The config lower in the output will override the values higher in the output. In your case, `my-User` >`ProgramData` > `Program Files`.  

`Program Files` is software installation while `Program Data` is equal to All User's profile. Individual user profiles (`C:/Users/<my-user/`) will override All User's profile