# git config showing duplicate entries

Tags: git

When I do a `git config --` I see the following (abridged) list:

```
$ git config --list
...
core.autocrlf=true
...
core.safecrlf=true
core.autocrlf=true
...
```

Notice *core.autocrlf=true* is repeated. I then try setting their values to false "globally" with `git config --global core.autocrlf false` and only the 2nd instance changes:

```
$ git config --list
...
core.autocrlf=true
...
core.safecrlf=true
core.autocrlf=false
...
```

I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928903/git-config-list-shows-duplicate-names) that using the *--show-origin* flag clarifies the source of each:

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:C:/Users/schmoejoe/.gitconfig      core.autocrlf=true
```

And that answer also notes the order of precedence (local > global > system). So my question is: Is there a way to change the values for each of these from the command line (whether with separate commands or all at once)?

Comment: I hope you've checked out http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/core-autocrlf-considered-half-assed-td4684075.html in summary autocrlf is broken (And that's the main git devs there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES):

> If not set explicitly with --file, there are four files where git config will search for configuration options:...
>
> The files are read in the order given above, with last value found taking precedence over values read earlier. When multiple values are taken then all values of a key from all files will be used.

Note that you can get this documentation by typing

```
git help config
```

or by googling "git config".

Comment: Thanks! I modified the question a bit, but this is really helpful. Do you know if I can modify the values in those various locations from the command line?

Comment: @JWoodchuck Yes you can. I refer you to the documentation for details of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`git config` command-line had mangled my local `.git/config` file badly (e.g., duplicate, conflicting entries):

```
...
[user]
  name = john_doe
  name = joe_blow
  name = jim_bob
  email = john_doe@yahoo.com
  email = john_bob@gmail.com
  email = john_@hotmail.com
...
```

I found it easier to fix up `.git/config` in an editor:

```
...
[user]
  name = john_doe
  email = john_doe@yahoo.com
...
```